# How to take the text string from the push notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an Iphone application in which i am recieving push notifications from the server.Now i am going to a view controller to show the message.Where that same message is loaded in a tableview .so thats not a problem.Now i am recieving two kinds of messages,one is a link and another is the message as earlier.if it is a link i want to open it in saffari,not need to go to tableview as usual.Can anybody help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You click on the push notification then you get a dictionary in the function -  `didReceiveRemoteNotification:`

try this code:-

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
        NSLog(@"remote notification: %@",[userInfo description]);

        if (userInfo)
        {
            if ([[userInfo allKeys] containsObject:@"aps"])
            {
                if([[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] allKeys] containsObject:@"alert"])
                {
                    if([[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] allKeys] containsObject:@"alert"])
                    {
                        NSString *urlString = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];
                        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

                        if(url)     
                        {
                            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];  // open in the safari...
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            //  use the message in table view


                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The push notification is tied to your application, so in short its not possible to have a push notification from you application open safari directly. However, one workaround might go something like this:

- user responds to notification (ie swipes to open it on the lock screen)
- your app opens, and the data from the notification is passed into your applications
  `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method. You could then interrogate the the data passed in as so

  ```
  NSDictionary *dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];

  // If dictionary is not nil, then your app is launched due to a push notification
  if (dictionary != nil) {

      NSDictionary *payload = [tmpDic objectForKey:@"aps"]; 
  }
  ```
- Once you've got your payload, look at the contents, and if it is a URL, call the safari URL scheme, passing in the URL. Like so

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: <URL from payload>]];`

This will help you achieve what you want to do, but it may mean the user briefly sees your app first before the os will switch them into safari.

A side note, why would you want to do this? Your users should not be launching a random URL from a notification, and I don't think Apple would like that too much. Prehaps they should be seeing some information about the URL first in your app, and then choosing whether they would like to open it in safari?